# Data processing from .txt with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Ok so i have a txt file containing values from 40 to 400 like this: 40 50 60...etc.
I have two '' in my html and i want the values of second to be greater than selected from first.

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="value_from">From</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="value_from" name="value_from">
            <?php
                $txt = file('includes/file.txt');
                echo '<option>--</option>';
                foreach ($txt as $line) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$line.'">'.$line.'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="value_to">To</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="value_to" name="value_to">
            <?php
                $txt = file('includes/file.txt');
                echo '<option>--</option>';
                foreach ($txt as $line) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$line.'">'.$line.'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ajax to handle it looks like this

```
$(document).on('change', '#values_from', function() {
        $('#galia_iki').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/file.txt',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {param1: 'value1'},
            success: function(data){
                $('#values_to').html('');
                $('#values_to').append('<option>--</option>')
                var array = data.split('\n');
                var from = $('#values_from').children(':selected').attr('value');
                console.log(nuo);
                $(array).each(function(index, el) {
                    if (el>from) {
                        console.log(el);
                        $('#values_to').append('<option value="'+el+'">'+el+'</option>')
                    }
                });
            }
        });                    
    });
```

but what happens when i check `if(el>from)` it doesn't return proper values. E.g if I choose 40 from first list I get weird values:

> 40 
>   50 
>   60
>   70
>   80
>   90
>   400

so what happens to values inbetween? Am I missing something in my code? By the way, I have two more groups like this with same code but different values and it runs fine. 
Also, if i select 90 it doesn't return any values. If anything over 100 it returns all the values, even less than selected.

Comment: Convert from to number

Comment: Thank You! You saved me!